# mysql, php - character encoding problem`

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm doing a project with zend framework and I'm pulling data from a utf-8 database. The project is utf-8 as well.

In a form, I have a select element displaying a list of countries. The problem is:
In french or spanish, some countries are not displayed.

After doing a var_dump() of my country list, I saw that those were the countries with special characters. Accented ones.

in the var_dump I could see the character represented as a ? in a diamond. I tried changing the encoding to iso-8859-1 and I could see the var_dump result with the special characters just fine.

How come data coming from a utf-8 database are displaying in iso-8859-1!

Can I store iso-8859-1 character set in a utf-8 table in mysql without problem? Shouldn't it display messed up characters?

confused.

--

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `geo_Country` (
  `CountryID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `CountryName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CountryCompleteName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Nationality` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CreationDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `LanguageCode` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `ZoneID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CountryID`,`LanguageCode`),
  KEY `fk_geo_Country_web_Language1` (`LanguageCode`),
  KEY `fk_geo_Country_geo_Zone` (`ZoneID`),
  KEY `idx_CountryName` (`CountryName`)
  CONSTRAINT `fk_geo_Country_geo_Zone` FOREIGN KEY (`ZoneID`) REFERENCES `geo_Zone` (`ZoneID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_geo_Country_web_Language1` FOREIGN KEY (`LanguageCode`) REFERENCES `web_Language` (`LanguageCode`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Comment: Could you please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` for the table involved and the relevant part of the PHP code you are running?

Comment: `I tried changing the encoding to iso-8859-1 ` - what encoding you tried to change and how?

Comment: Just the browser encoding to see how it behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to database you should set up cleint encoding.
for Zend_Db it seems should be like this (notice 'driver_options'):

```
$params = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'dbname' => 'dbname',
    'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8;');
);
```

for the application.ini

```
resources.db.params.charset = utf8
```

as a last resort you could just run this query `SET NAMES UTF8` manually just like any other query.

Comment: yeah I was looking around and it seems there waqs a mysql_query(SET NAMES UTF8) to add.

I will try that. I use a config file for my connection. I will see how it goes.

Comment: I tried my luck with this in the application.ini file:
resources.db.params.driver_options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8;')

with no success.

I had a gut feeling an array like that in a string wouldn't work well lol.

Comment: you know, i never used ZF myself. just googled for `zend framework database encoding`

Answer (score 3):

The thing to remember with UTF-8 is this:

**Everything in your entire application needs to be UTF-8!**

For a normal PHP/MySQL web application (a form, posting to a database), you need to check if:

1. Your database connection uses UTF-8 (execute this query right after your connection is set up: `SET NAMES UTF8;`)
2. Your PHP code uses UTF-8. That means no using character set translation/encoding functions (no need to when everything is UTF-8).
3. Your HTML output is UTF-8, by either sending a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8` header, of using a `<meta charset="utf8">` tag (for HTML5, for other HTML variants, use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">`)

In your case of `var_dump`'ing, there is just some plain text that is sent to the browser, without any mention of a character set. Looking at rule #3, this means your browser is displaying this in a different character set, presumably latin1, thus giving you the diamonds/question marks/blocks.

If you need to check if your data is stored properly, use a database client like PHPMyAdmin to view the record. This way you're viewing the content as UTF-8 (NOTE: this is a setting in PMA, so check if it is not set to a different charset!).

On a side note, set the collation of your databases' text columns to utf8_general_ci, this is not used for storing, but for sorting. So this isn't related to your problem, but it's a good practice to do so.

Comment: I think that 1) is my problem. I'm using zend framework and following Col. Shrapnel information I should configure that. Only, I use a configuration file and not a variable for my parameters.

2) that's good.
3) that's good.

My data did come from a iso-8859-1 database. I've loaded them with kettle and modified their encoding on the fly to utf-8. 

The test look-at-data-directly-in-db is successful (MSQL workbench!). So they are indeed utf-8 now.

This answer deserves at least a thumbs up even if my problem is not completely fixed yet!

Comment: ok. I thought about it and it's the answer. I just have another question for zend framework people.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There is not a single reason to have **Everything** in UTF-8. You can have the pafe in latin1 while your database in utf. it's not a big deal and allowed by design

Comment: and these `<meta>` tags has nothing to do with encoding. Only real HTTP header do

Comment: When displaying utf-8 data in a page that has a latin1 charset, special characters are displayed wrong, because they're not in the character set. The only way to do this, is by re-encoding the text to latin1 before outputting it. But I don't see any reason to do so.

Comment: And regarding the meta tag: "To address server or configuration limitations, HTML documents may include explicit information about the document's character encoding; the META element can be used to provide user agents with this information." http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2

Comment: okay, you can have contrary, latin1 database and utf-8 page. The point is there is no need to have everything in the same encoding. Mysql can recode charsets as long as there are characters in the destination charset to show. One more option (a lame) is to have whatever charset (1252) in the database and same connection. Everything would be shown correctly for the any page encoding. However, database search wouldn't work

Comment: While it's true what you're saying, I really don't see the need to point this out. The question is about special characters, stored in a utf-8 database, so regarding your first comment: there *is* a reason to have everything utf-8.

Comment: Yeah, it was merely a rant, I am sorry for that. To be able to show all languages characters everything should be in utf8, that's true.